# "Non-existent service" errors after clearing the cache

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

After clearing the cache in Drupal 8 (via the UI) I got "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." error. It happened for the first time. I haven't introduced any heavy changes to the site, basically only created a field and some features (via the Features module).

I've found this error in the logs:

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "password_migrate". in /.../app/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 800

To fix this was trying different things: clearing cache tables directly in the DB, trying drush rebuild (rebuild wasn't successful since it yelds the same error). After some time the error is different (and I don't know why):

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The service "ctools.paramconverter.tempstore" has  a dependency on a non-existent service "user.shared_tempstore". in /.../app/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/  Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php on line 58

I can *temporarily* get the site back to life by loading {cache_container} table from the old backup. But the site breaks again after clearing the cache and the first error reapers in logs.

The site is basically broken. How can I restore it? How is the {cache_container} populated, so I can reverse the process and restore what's missing based on the cache? Thanks!

Comment: When you get your site back, is there anything on admin/reports/status?

Comment: @MPD, thanks for the answer. Apart from "Trusted Host Settings", "Cron jobs" (to be run) and "Database version" (which I cannot update due to the error), there's also: "Entity/field definitions": "Mismatched entity and/or field definitions", but I don't think any of those is a cause of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me a while, but I managed to find the issue and to solve it.

The problem was directly caused by the Features module (or maybe rather it was directly caused by careless me...). Anyway, a couple of hours before I cleared the cache (this is when the issue manifested itself) I had exported some configuration as new features. Normally I would use some custom names, but this time I've just swum with the tide and added the configuration to the features that Features module proposed. And one of the proposed features was "User" with machine name "user", which is exactly the same as the core module! This is why "password_migrate" service couldn't be found, Drupal was looking at the new feature instead of the core module.

Because the module name was already in core.extension configuration I didn't even have to enable it, as it was already enabled (unlike in the old {system} table there's no path to the module in the config so probably Drupal just used the first definition it found). After exporting the feature the problem was there, sleeping, and it was just when I cleared the cache some time later when the site broke (probably if the problem appeared right away I could track it down much earlier).

The problem went away as soon as I deleted the feature.

Comment: You saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that a class is requesting the password_migrate service which does not exist.

This is usually caused when the module that supplies this service is not installed.

I suggest you search the project code for the string password_migrate to find both the requester and the provider.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `password_migrate` service is provided by the core user module (and the service's class `MigratePassword` exists in the module). I couldn't find any dependency on this service, but there's a `$container->setDefinition('password', $container->getDefinition('password_migrate'));` call in the very same module in the `UserServiceProvider` class. The user module is enabled.

Comment: What version (including minor) of drupal are you running?

Comment: Pretty weird. `admin/reports/status` says it's 8.0.6, but in `web/core/CHANGELOG.txt` the most recent entry is 8.0.4.