# "RuntimeException: You have requested a non-existent parameter 'app.root'"

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

After I clear the cache, I get this message.

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "app.root". in Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DefinitionErrorExceptionPass->processValue() (line 37 of /var/www/call/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/DefinitionErrorExceptionPass.php).
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DefinitionErrorExceptionPass->processValue() (Line: 60)
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\AbstractRecursivePass->processValue() (Line: 30)
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DefinitionErrorExceptionPass->processValue() (Line: 39)
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\AbstractRecursivePass->process() (Line: 140)
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile() (Line: 789)
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() (Line: 1335)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->compileContainer() (Line: 916)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 477)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 707)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)

Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: The second line says `You have requested a non-existent parameter "app.root".`  Try searching your code base for `app.root` and see where you are requiring it.

Comment: All are related to drupal console

Comment: What version of Drupal console?  Are you sure the version is compatible with 8.9.20?

Comment: "drupal/console": "^1.9",

Comment: Remove Drupal Console and retry.

Comment: same problem, same error

Answer (score 3):

This error is caused by code using `%app.root%` as parameter in Drupal 8.

For example:

```
   cache.backend.apcu:
     class: Drupal\Core\Cache\ApcuBackendFactory
     arguments: ['%app.root%', '%site.path%', '@cache_tags.invalidator.checksum']
```

This is Drupal 9 code not working in Drupal 8.

The service argument `@app.root` on the other hand is not causing this error. You find it in Drupal Console or other Drupal 8 code. It was deprecated in Drupal 9, but is still working until you update to
Drupal 10. Then it will be this error ["Non-existent service" errors after clearing the cache](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199005/non-existent-service-errors-after-clearing-the-cache)

See the change record https://www.drupal.org/node/3080612.

Answer (score 3):

The *app.root* parameter has been added in Drupal 9 to replace the *app.root* service. If you are using Drupal 8, that error could possibly be causes by:

- A module that says to be compatible with Drupal 8 and Drupal 9, whose code accesses the *app.root* container parameter when it runs on Drupal 8
- Other code that tries to access the *app.root* container parameter when it runs on Drupal 8

This could happen because:

- One of the arguments for a service is `'%app.root%'` (which requires the container parameter) instead of `'@app.root'` (which requires the service that exists in Drupal 8.x)
- There is code that uses `$container->getParameter('app.root')` instead of `$container->get('app.root')`
- There is code that checks whether to use the *app.root* container parameter or the *app.root* service, but it fails to use the available one

To understand which code causes the error, it should be sufficient to search for *%app.root%* or *->getParameter('app.root')*. Searching for *app.root* isn't sufficient, as it would return any line that correctly uses the *app.root* service.

[[Symfony 5] Replace app.root and site.path string services with container parameters has been created](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3074585) has been created on August 13, 2019 and marked as fixed on December 23, 2020. (The patch was committed on Drupal 9.x on March 5, 2020.)
Drupal Console 1.9.4 (released on November 11, 2019) should not contain code that accesses the *app.root* container parameter, as Drupal core didn't even have that container parameter when Drupal Console 1.9.4 was released.