# Why does the error 'You have requested a non-existent parameter "site.path"' occur on module configure buttons?

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

When I click some configuration buttons for example in layout builder UI or the following buttons. [image]
I get the following error in admin/reports/dblog

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException:
You have requested a non-existent parameter "site.path". en Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->getParameter() 
(linea 328 de /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php)
```

A coworker with the same local but using windows (without wsl) has everything working normally. I used docker and ddev on ubuntu 22.04 LTS and on windows but with wsl, it doesn't work on both. Could it be something about permissions? I have sites/default/files and sites/default with a+w permissions

As the title says I am using Drupal 8.9.20 and I really do not know what to do.

If you need more information just ask me for it and I will edit the post.

Debugger data when gets to line 328
[image]

Comment: The error says that some module or theme on the site is referencing 'site.path', which is not an existing container parameter. I think the parameter is called '@site.path': https://www.drupal.org/node/3080612

Comment: Yeah I check that but I wasn't able to find a 'site.path' reference without the @

Comment: This is similar to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/309827/runtimeexception-you-have-requested-a-non-existent-parameter-app-root

Comment: I check that too but I'm not using %site.path% anywhere

Comment: You will have to use a debugger then. I don't think we can answer the question without more information.

Comment: What other information could I provide in order to help you to help me :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145103/discussion-between-cilefen-and-jordi-bustos).

Comment: It looks like this is caused by the anchor_link module. What is the version of this module on the site?

Comment: I updated the post with some useful info. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the module [CKEditor Anchor Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/anchor_link):

*/modules/contrib/anchor_link/src/Plugin/CKEditorPlugin/AnchorLink.php*

```
 /**
   * Get the CKEditor Link library path.
   */
  protected function getLibraryPath() {
    // Following the logic in Drupal 8.9.x and Drupal 9.x
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Issue #3096648: Add support for third party libraries in site specific
    // and install profile specific libraries folders
    // https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3096648
    //
    // https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/commit/1edf15f
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Search sites/<domain>/*.
    $directories[] = \Drupal::getContainer()->getParameter('site.path') . "/libraries/";
```

The last line listed works only in Drupal >=9.

You will find an increasing number of modules switching to Drupal 9/10 because [Drupal 8 is no longer supported](https://www.drupal.org/psa-2021-06-29). The only issue here is that the module is still marked as `Works with Drupal: ^8 || ^9 || ^10`.

You either need to upgrade to Drupal 9 (recommended) or downgrade the module.

As a quick fix, until you find time to upgrade to Drupal 9, you can patch this code line to work with Drupal 8:

```
$directories[] = \Drupal::service('site.path') . "/libraries/";
```